# Подсчёт количества использований макросов надстройки

Tags: vba

Я создал по работе надстройку для Excel, в надстройку входят 12 модулей, каждый из которых выполняет свою задачу и посажен на кнопку. Надстройку я делал в программе RibbonXMLEditor. Лежит она сетевом диске и используется 15-ю пользователями. Вопрос в том, реально ли организовать подсчёт количества использований всех макросов с выводом этой суммы на панель Надстройки, или в какое другое меню.

p.s. Задал этот же вопрос на другом форуме: с ответом мне помог Дмитрий Щербаков под ником The_Prist. В итоге, задача была решена на 98%, остались нюансы, которые я, как ни пытался, решить не смог, а автор кода продолжать диалог не может или не хочет. Кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста как добить эту задачу?!! Суть такова, в ниже приведённом коде сам Счётчик работает и отрабатывает, но с недочётами:1) Каждый раз когда запускается Excel и подгружается моя Надстройка, счётчик воспринимает это как запуск макроса и соответственно добавляет +1 к значению счётчика(такого быть не должно,счётчик должен считать только запуски макросов после нажатия соответствующих кнопок). 2) Если во время использования какого-либо макроса возникает ошибка или срабатывает блок проверки if...then end, то значение счётчика на панели Надстройки сбрасывается в ноль, и последующие использования макросов хоть и добавляют к значению счётчика на панели Надстройки +1, но в текстовый файл(куда записывается/считывается значение счётчика) это значение уже не добавляется. Следовательно при закрытии/открытии Excel, на панель Надстройки выводится старое значение Счётчика, а именно, сохранённое значение предыдущего ЗАПУСКА Надстройки Excel(не путать с последним удачным использованием макроса), плюс 1(так как запуск Excel ошибочно принимается за использование макроса см.выше). Я пытался бороться со сбросом Счётчика в ноль таким образом: вместо End - я создавал метку Go to PreEnd и устанавливал её непосредственно перед End Sub, тогда на панели Надстройки Счётчик действительно не сбрасывался в ноль и плюсовался, но в текстовый файл это значение после закрытия не записывалось, и после закрытия/открытия Excel подгружалось значение предыдущей сохранённой!

Так выглядит код XML-разметки для Счётчика и 2 кнопок:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Init_RibVar_Custom">
    <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
        <tabs>
            <tab id="excel-vba" label="Счетчик">
                <group id="groupe_1" label=" ">
                    <button id="button_1" imageMso="GoLtrDown" label="Кнопка 1" onAction="macro1" />
                    <button id="button_2" imageMso="GoLtrDown" label="Кнопка 2" onAction="macro2" />
                </group>

                <group id="gr1" label="Счетчик">
                    <labelControl id="Счетчик" getLabel="getLabel_Cnt" />
                </group>

            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Так выглядит основной код:

```
Option Explicit
'для считывания и записи в память данных о Ribbon
#If VBA7 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As LongPtr)
#Else
Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#End If

Public MyCounter As Long 'Переменная-счётчик
Public objRibCustom As IRibbonUI
Public cntr As IRibbonControl

'Процедура проверяет, потеряна ли ссылка.
'Если ссылка потеряна, то восстанавливает её из именованного диапазона.
Sub CheckRibbon()
    If objRibCustom Is Nothing Then
#If VBA7 Then
        Dim lPointer As LongPtr
        lPointer = CLngPtr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1").Range("A1"))
#Else
        Dim lPointer As Long
        lPointer = CLng(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1").Range("A1"))
#End If
        CopyMemory objRibCustom, lPointer, LenB(lPointer)
    End If
End Sub
Sub Init_RibVar_Custom(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set objRibCustom = ribbon
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1").Range("A1") = ObjPtr(ribbon)
    objRibCustom.Invalidate
    Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Input As #1 ' код в начале макроса
    Input #1, MyCounter
    Close #1
    MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
    Call getLabel_Cnt(cntr, "")
    Open "D:\Counter.txt" For Output As #1 ' код в конце макроса
    Print #1, MyCounter
    Close #1
End Sub
Sub getLabel_Cnt(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
    Call CheckRibbon
    If cntr Is Nothing Then
        Set cntr = control
    End If
    label = "Счетчик: " & MyCounter
    On Error Resume Next
    objRibCustom.InvalidateControl control.ID
    objRibCustom.Invalidate
End Sub
Sub macro1(control As IRibbonControl)
     MsgBox "Тест! Первая кнопка", vbOKOnly"
End Sub
Sub macro2(control As IRibbonControl)
     MsgBox ("Тест! Вторая кнопка", vbYesNo)= vbNo Then
       End 
End Sub
```

Comment: Количество запусков каждого макроса? Количество всех запусков? Запуски каждым пользователем? Зачем? В чем смысл этой затеи?

Comment: Общее количество запусков всех макросов всеми пользователями, на выходе просто одно число. Практически, никакого смысла в этой затее нет, это для себя.